# concatenate two txt files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm beginner in python, I have  two space delimited text files,
the first looks like:

```
a b c
d e f
```

the second looks like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

I want to concatenate them vertically such that the output is:

```
a b c 
d e f
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

how can I do that using python?
and if I want to concatenate horizontally so it looks like this:

```
a b c 1 2 3
d e f 4 5 6
```

how can I do it also?

Comment: You can load both of em into lists of rows, and then merge em into one list and write that to a file for the first output. Can you post you attempt so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that, using [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
with open("File1", 'r') as f:
    file1 = f.read().split("\n")
with open("File2", 'r') as f:
    file2 = f.read().split("\n")

vertically = "\n".join(file1 + file2)
print(vertically)

horizontally = "\n".join([" ".join(line) for line in zip(file1, file2)])
print(horizontally)
```

---

To save:

```
with open("File3.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(vertically)

with open("File4.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(horizontally)
```

Comment: thanks a lot but this only printed the output and didn't  save in a new txt file, if you can tell how to save the output in a new txt file I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first output something like this should work.

```
fin = open("File2.txt", "r")
data2 = fin.read()
fin.close()

fout = open("File1.txt", "a")
fout.write(data2)
fout.close()
```

For the 2nd one you can try this

```
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
```

for both files, and then combine index 1 in both, and index 2 in both, and make the final merged list and write it to a file.